# How to correctly use dynamic inventories with Ansible?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to provide initial configuration and software installation to a newly created AWS EC2 instance by using Ansible. If I run my playbooks independently it works just as I want. However, if I try to automate it into a single playbook by using two imports, it doesn't work (probably because the dynamic inventory can't get the newly created IP address?)...

Running together:

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring:
aws_region_eu_central_1

PLAY [variables from dynamic inventory] ****************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

Running separately:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
[WARNING]: Platform linux on host XX.XX.XX.XX is using the discovered Python
interpreter at /usr/bin/python, but future installation of another Python
interpreter could change the meaning of that path. See https://docs.ansible.com
/ansible/2.10/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more
information.
ok: [XX.XX.XX.XX]
```

This is my main playbook:

```
- import_playbook: server-setup.yml
- import_playbook: server-configuration.yml
```

server-setup.yml:

```
---
# variables from dynamic inventory
- name: variables from dynamic inventory
  remote_user: ec2-user
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - ec2-instance
```

server-configuration.yml:

```
---
# variables from dynamic inventory
- name: variables from dynamic inventory
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  ignore_unreachable: true
  hosts: aws_region_eu_central_1
  gather_facts: false

  pre_tasks:
    - pause:
        minutes: 5

  roles:
    - { role: epel, sudo: true }
    - { role: nodejs, sudo: true }
```

This is my ansible.cfg file:

```
[defaults]
inventory = test_aws_ec2.yaml
private_key_file = master-key.pem
enable_plugins = aws_ec2
host_key_checking = False
pipelining = True
log_path = ansible.log
roles_path = /roles
forks = 1000
```

and finally my hosts.ini:

```
[local]
localhost ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Comment: Bob, the thing that stands out is the `hosts: localhost` on the first playbook. So you might want to look at that. But to help farther: can you a) provide the test_aws_ec2.yaml file, b) provide the full ansible-playbook command you are using, and c) explain what you mean by: "probably because the dynamic inventory can't get the newly created IP address?" as I don't know what you mean by that.